# What is the difference between SADD vs PFADD?

Tags: redis

I am looking to have a set which will store elements and that I can get the cardinality after. I noticed I could use the commands SADD or PFADD then use SCARD or PFCOUNT. What is the difference between these two? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using SADD, you store data in a [SET](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sets).

When using PFADD, you store data in an [Hyperloglog](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#hyperloglogs), which is a different kind of data structure.

A SET is used to store unique values, when you have to access again these values.

An HyperLogLog allows to get an approximate count of the number of unique values in the data added using PFADD. It is useful when you have a great number of distinct values and don't need to get them back. It may be used by example to get the number of unique visitors for a given day for a given page on a high traffic web site (you just add the unique visitor IDs to the HLL).

Answer (score 1):

SADD and SCARD are for "Set".

PFADD and PFCOUNT are for "HyperLogLog".

Advantage of "HyperLogLog":

#### "HyperLogLog" takes much less memory than "Set".

---

This video below explains about "HyperLogLog" precisely in about 5 minutes.

https://youtu.be/UAL2dxl1fsE